# Confusions on /account/ vs /admin/ views (any built in way to create these)

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-admin

I have begun to implement authentication throughout my applications in Django and have done this quite successfully with the Django login_required decorator.

However, I notice that this will always reroute to the deafault login URL: `/accounts/...` which is non-existent for me. I have been doing all my authentication through `/admin/...`

I imagine that the two are for different purposes (one for the admin users and allow access to the admin console) however, I cannot find any views for the accounts version (vs. admin). My questions are thus as follows:

1. What is the difference between `/accounts/...` and `/admin/...` if they use the same user models?
2. Are these `/accounts/...` views built in/templateable? How does one turn them on? Or do I need to create each manually?

Unfortunately I have found the documentation on this topic to be rather confusing and as such any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '/accounts/' is just a url that out of best practices most people when handling authentication. There are no built in templates for accounts. the '/accounts/' is just a default placed.

To change the url to fit your applications url, go to your *settings.py* file and you can add a **LOGIN_URL** variable to specify which location for the authentication to redirect to. In your case it will look like this.

```
LOGIN_URL = '/admin'
```

This will redirect all unauthenticated requests to '/admin'

Answer (score 2):

If you are not logged in, Django uses the [`LOGIN_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#login-url) to decide which url to redirect to. By default, this is set to `'/accounts/login/'`.

If you use a different login url, then you should update your `LOGIN_URL` setting.

The disadvantage of using the Django admin to log in users, is that non-staff members will not be able to log in using the Django admin.

Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), including a [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) view. If you want to allow non-staff members to log in, you should enable it.